# Allow special characters in Web Api Get function

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to pass a special characters to a custom function in Web API. The function works if I don't pass special characters. The special characters that I am referring to are '#' ,'&' ,....

```
[HttpGet]
[EnableQuery(MaxExpansionDepth = 5)]
public IQueryable<Test> QueryTest(string Query)
{
    var dbTest = db.Test.AsQueryable();
    return dbTest;
}
```

Comment: Which characters are you referring to and what exactly happens?

Comment: The characters probably have to be encoded in order to be received correctly by the backend and not be treated as something else by the HTTP protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to use a post method and pass your parameter through a json object in the body message.

```
[HttpPost]
public IQueryable<Test> QueryTest(QueryTestRequest request)
{
    var dbTest = db.Test.AsQueryable();
    return dbTest;
}

public class QueryTestRequest
{
   public string Query {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

URL encoding is the way to go. This should be done as a default you don't even think of, solves so many issues. Set the Encoding of the WebClient

```
client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
```

Comment: Thank you .Where do I need to do that